# Inno Setup Constant in Code Section

Tags: inno-setup, setuptools

Is there a way to get InnoSetup constant value in [Code] section? I need this during install time and the constant value that I am trying to get is `{app}`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use  `AppValue := ExpandConstant('{app}');`

- [Documentation on ExpandConstant](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_expandconstant.htm)
- [Example of it's usage](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptconstants.htm).